# How to access outer class's property from an inner enum-class?

Tags: kotlin, enums, static

I tried to access `var1` with two *enum* variants: `A2` and `A3`.

```
class OutA {

    var var1 = ""

    inner class A {
        init {
            print(var1)
        }
    }

    enum class A2 {
        ;

        init {
        print(var1)//unresolved reference:var1
        }
    }

    inner enum class A3 {//Modifier 'inner' is not applicable to 'enum class'
        ;

        init {
            print(var1)
        }
    }
}
```

but they can't compile.

A2 reports `unresolved reference:var1` and another condition says `Modifier 'inner' is not applicable to` .

*Why isn't possible to access `var1` outer property from *enum* scopes?*

**EDIT:** removed screenshot, updated title and description to promote a reopening of the question.

Comment: Images of code are absolutely useless. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should avoid posting images. Code and errors are in text, and should be posted as such. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with this site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Comment: @KenWhite - thanks for the meta post link. Adding to my SO notes (and just used it with another question).

Comment: @DavidMakogon: You're welcome. It seems to be used pretty frequently by quite a few people. Shame that there's no rep for [meta]. :-)

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question: it contains a code sample, an error message, and a question about the error message. It also produced a clear and usable answer. The user even read the first comment and replaced the image with text.  What more do you want? It shouldn't have been closed. Typical SO users with 50k+ picking on a newbie.

Comment: *Edited to fix few things in the answer* – I voted for reopening it. @DavidMakogon I see you voted for closing it; would you please reconsider it? It's readable now and has a good clear accepted answer, that imho would benefit SO users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enum constants need to exist without having to be initialized explicitly, whereas the surrounding class `OutA` needs to be created first. You cannot access non-static values from static contexts. Making the class a singleton, i.e. an `object`, will make the code compile though:

```
object OutA {
    var var1 = ""

    enum class A2 {
        ;
        init {
            print(var1)
        }
    }
}
```

This works because an instance (the only one) of `OutA` is being created by the compiler and its `var1` will be available for the enum to access.